# How to use opencv reduce using cv2 python API

Tags: python, opencv

I checked [the documentation](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=reduce#cv2.reduce) but its incomplete: there is no mention of what `rtype` parameter actually is.

I think it's a reduce type but I can't find any of variables like `cv2.CV_REDUCE_SUM` etc... I found this problem with many function that use different variable names. What's the best way to find proper names in cv2 API?

Comment: have you tried `dir(cv2)` or `help(cv2)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out that the appropriate variable can be found in the following package

```
cv2.cv
```

If you use CV_REDUCE_SUM operator on **uint8** image you have to explicitly provide dtype parameter of bigger range to avoid overflowing (e.g.

```
slice = cv2.reduce(image, 1, cv2.cv.CV_REDUCE_SUM, dtype=numpy.int32)
```

If you use CV_REDUCE_AVG operation, result can't overflow that's why setting dtype is optional.

Comment: The parameter of dtype will cause error:
`TypeError: an integer is required`
Use `cv2.CV_32S` instead.

Answer (score 4):

There are some omisions in the current new cv2 lib. Typically these are constants that did not get migrated to cv2 yet and are still in cv only. Here is some code to help you find them:

```
import cv2
import cv2.cv as cv
nms  = [(n.lower(), n) for n in dir(cv)] # list of everything in the cv module
nms2 = [(n.lower(), n) for n in dir(cv2)] # list of everything in the cv2 module

search = 'window'

print "in cv2\n ",[m[1] for m in nms2 if m[0].find(search.lower())>-1]
print "in cv\n ",[m[1] for m in nms if m[0].find(search.lower())>-1]
```

Comment: And in OpenCV 3, cv2.cv doesn't exist anymore + some constant name have changed, see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/33199152/5075502

Answer (score 2):

If you're finding this while using Open CV 3.x or later, these constants have been renamed to `cv2.REDUCE_SUM`, `cv2.REDUCE_AVG`, `cv2.REDUCE_MAX`, and `cv2.REDUCE_MIN`.

An example of the working reduce function:

```
reducedArray = cv2.reduce(im, 0, cv2.REDUCE_MAX)
```

[GitHub issue for documentation](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/9008)