# What is the cv2.cv replacement in OpenCV3?

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0

I'm using OpenCV3, and with the python bindings there is no `cv2.cv` module:

```
In [1]: import cv2

In [2]: from cv2 import cv
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-15a6578c139c> in <module>()
----> 1 from cv2 import cv

ImportError: cannot import name cv
```

However, I have some legacy code of the form:

```
hsv_im = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.cv.CV_BGR2HSV)
```

When running this, I get the error:

```
In [7]: hsv_im = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.cv.CV_BGR2HSV)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-e784072551f2> in <module>()
----> 1 hsv_im = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.cv.CV_BGR2HSV)

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cv'
```

What is the equivalent of this code in OpenCV3?

---

### Related questions:

- [import cv2 works but import cv2.cv as cv not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292070/import-cv2-works-but-import-cv2-cv-as-cv-not-working)
- [Is cv2.cv missing in OpenCV 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132081/is-cv2-cv-missing-in-opencv-3-0)

Comment: `import cv2`, `cv2.someFunction` [shoud work](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d00/tutorial_py_root.html#gsc.tab=0)

Comment: @Miki thanks, but it doesn't in this case because the cv2.cv module doesn't exist in the version of OpenCV I have, but the code I have uses it.

Comment: just a guess, but can you try with `hsv_im = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)` ?

Comment: Yup, thanks, this is the one! Put it as an answer and I will accept...

Comment: added an answer. Glad it works :D

Answer (score 40, accepted):

From OpenCV 2.X OpenCV 3.0 a few things [changed](http://docs.opencv.org/master/db/dfa/tutorial_transition_guide.html#gsc.tab=0).

Specifically:

- `cv2.cv` doesn't exists in OpenCV 3.0. Use simply `cv2`.
- some defines changed, e.g. `CV_BGR2HSV` is now `COLOR_BGR2HSV`.

---

So you need to change this line:

```
hsv_im = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.cv.CV_BGR2HSV)
```

to:

```
hsv_im = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
```

Comment: How about cv.CalcBackProjectPatch ?

Comment: what about `AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE'` ?

Comment: @MonaJalal,  see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30013069/4325994